# Git gives a strange date error

Tags: git, freebsd

I'm struck with my remote virtual server. I'm trying by many ways to push/pull a project(IDE, FreeBSD bash, Windows git bash) like this:

```
git clone username@ipaddr:/full/path/to_repo
```

but everytime i'm gettin

date: illegal option -- c
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Server is FreeBSD 8.2 with git 1.7.6

Please tell me what's wrong!!

Comment: This looks like an error in git's support of FreeBSD. You should probably ask this on the git mailing list: git@vger.kernel.org.

Comment: What happens if you just `ssh username@ipaddr` ?  Can you login without errors?  Can you run `git` once logged into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hosting provider helped my figure it out =)

User that i used to connect to git deamon didn't have a shell. Instad it had /bin/date in /etc/passwd

Hope this will be helpful for somebody else =)